# Does piping write to stdin?

Tags: linux

Does running something like below cause the textfile lines to be directed to the STDIN of program.sh?

```
cat textfile | program.sh
```

Comment: Yes! That's what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; and the rest of this answer comes to satisfy SO's requirement of minimum 30 characters per answer (excluding links).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You're writing the stdout from `cat` to the stdin of `program.sh`. Because `cat` isn't doing much except reading the file, you can also write it as:

```
program.sh < textfile
```

...which [does the same thing](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

From a technical standpoint, stdin is accessed through file descriptor 0, while stdout is file descriptor 1 and stderr is file descriptor 2. With this information, you can make more complicated redirections, such as redirecting stderr to the same place (or a different place!) than stdout. For a cheat sheet about redirections, see Peteris Krumins's [Bash Redirections Cheat Sheet](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You are running the command `sort` on a text file. The output goes to `program.sh`